# Automation run viewed by all users?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, protractor

We have a Jenkins job setup which runs all the automation scripts on vm. Is there a way for multiple people to view the tests running (chrome instance) when they are logged in to that vm?

Comment: yes when you login do you see automation code getting executed in vm ?

Comment: @cruisepandey I do see it running but other people cannot.

Comment: @cruisepandey Any update for this? Appreciate your help!